# Analyzer claiming an object was released when it wasn't

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, objective-c++

I am getting a static analysis error in this code which doesn't make any sense to me. The error is:

> Reference-counted object is used after it is released

This is glue code to allow for PNG loading in a game originally written in C++.

```
int pngLoad(const char *filename, pngInfo *info, int format, GLuint *textureName)
{
    char fullPath[Engine::Settings::MaxPath];
    strcpy(fullPath, filename);
    appendAppBundlePath(fullPath);

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithCString:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    [data release];

    Texture2D *loadedTex = [Texture2D alloc];

    // ##### Analyzer claims the object is released here: #####
    [loadedTex initWithImage:image format:format];

    int didLoad;

    // ##### Error is here: #####
    if (loadedTex.contentSize.width == 0 || loadedTex.contentSize.height == 0)
    {
        didLoad = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        didLoad = 1;

        *textureName = loadedTex.name;

        // return texture info
        info->ScaleFactor = loadedTex.scaleFactor;
        info->Width = (float)image.size.width / (float)info->ScaleFactor;
        info->Height = (float)image.size.height / (float)info->ScaleFactor;
        info->Alpha = 1;
        info->PaddedWidth = loadedTex.pixelsWide;
        info->PaddedHeight = loadedTex.pixelsHigh;
    }

    [loadedTex release];
    [image release];

    return didLoad;
}
```

If I use `Texture2D *loadedTex = [[Texture2D alloc] retain];` this warning is removed, but then an warning that I've leaked an object comes up, so something is seriously weird here.

`initWithImage:format:` used to contain a `[self release]` which shouldn't have been there, which I removed when I found this warning. However, even after a full clean and rebuild, I still get the warning. Am I doing something else wrong? Is something not getting properly cleaned up by the Clean command in Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer may be right, at least in a general way.

```
Texture2D *loadedTex = [Texture2D alloc];
[loadedTex initWithImage:image format:format];
```

In general, "init" might actually discard the object passed in and return a different one. Whether or not this is the case for "Texture2D" is something I don't know, but if the analyzer is going for the general case then it is right.

You should be able to work around that by using

```
Texture2D *loadedTex = [Texture2D alloc];
loadedTex=[loadedTex initWithImage:image format:format];
```

Or by simply combining the two calls, as it is done in most Objective-C examples.

Comment: I wonder if this could be behind another odd bug in my texture loading. On rare random occasion I had one object taking a texture from another object in the level. I'll probably ask about this in a separate question later if this doesn't fix it. It's unlikely though, as I don't see any code in the `Texture2D` class that discards the object and returns a different one. It's a modified version of the `Texture2D` from the old apple CrashLanding example.

Comment: It could still be the problem, depending on what the superclass does. If Texture2D is derived from NSObject then it won't do any "discard and return a different one"; I know that Apple specifically mentions it in some cases, but I don't know whether they ALWAYS mention it. So, it's always better to assume that it can happen

Comment: As a slightly related follow-up, it turns out the rare bug I mentioned was caused by an uninitialized C string in some C++ code. Garbage data would sometimes contain the data from a previously loaded image, causing some pretty funky problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should always combine the `alloc` and `initXXX` call when creating objects, in this case

```
Texture2D *loadedTex = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithImage:image format:format];
```

An init method need not return the same object it was called with, it is allowed to return a different object.

In this case your result from `loadedTex = [Texture2D alloc]` would be released and `initWithImage` would return a different object (which you discard).